# Unable to get a list with reflection using list name as string

Tags: c#, reflection

I want the new list called classAssets to be a copy of the list that has the name of the parameter.

```
private List<Transform> noviceAssets = new List<Transform>();

public void ActivateClassAssets(string className) {
    string listName = className.ToLower() + "Assets";

    List<Transform> classAssets = new List<Transform> 
    ((List<Transform>)GetType().GetProperty(listName).GetValue(this, null));

    for(int i = 0; i < classAssets.Count; i++) {
        classAssets[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a dictionary. A key in this dictionary is the name of a list, the associated value would be the list object itself. No need to create dozens of properties/fields and fighting with reflection if you can just use a simple dictionary...

Comment: Ah good idea, thank you!